# I have 2 problems with conditional probability, involving coins and dice

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

Hi I have these problems:

```
A coin is tossed three times. What is the probability that exactly two heads
occur, given that
(a) the ﬁrst outcome was a head?
(b) the ﬁrst outcome was a tail?
(c) the ﬁrst two outcomes were heads?
(d) the ﬁrst two outcomes were tails?
(e) the ﬁrst outcome was a head and the third outcome was a head?
```

Which I have done it like:

```
T1 T2 T3

H  H  H
H  H  T
H  T  H
H  T  T
T  H  H
T  H  T
T  T  H 
T  T  T
```

I put all the outcomes, then by counting them by hand:

```
p(2H|T1=H)=2/4
p(2H|T1=T)=1/4
p(2H|T1=H,T2=H)=1/2
p(2H|T1=T,T2=T)=0
p(2H|T1=H,T3=H)=1/2
```

Is this correct? Then, is there another way of doing it? Counting by hand just feel wrong, there must be a formal way.

Then:

```
A die is rolled twice. What is the probability that the sum of the faces is
greater than 7, given that
(a) the ﬁrst outcome was a 4?
(b) the ﬁrst outcome was greater than 3?
(c) the ﬁrst outcome was a 1?
(d) the ﬁrst outcome was less than 5?
```

Again counting, this really feels so wrong, I'm expecting some formula to get them.

```
p(sum>7|D1=4)=3/6
p(sum>7|D1>3)=12/18
p(sum>7|D1=1)=0/6
p(sum>7|D1<5)=6/24
```

Am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: Your answer to `p(2H|T1=T)` is wrong (I didn't check any after that).

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct "long" way to do it. Essentially any combinatorics problem could be solved this way with enough ink and paper or computing power. This seems a bit like homework, so I'll get you started in the right direction without giving the answer away completely. You've got a bunch of conditional probabilities $P(A|B)$ that you need to calculate. Use Bayes Theorem to write

$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \mbox{ and } B)}{P(B)}$

Now finding these probabilities should be straightforward from the distribution of 3 coin flips. (Hint, it starts with a "B".)

Also, be careful to think about your joint probabilities (the "and"s). For example, the event of getting 2 heads and getting a heads on both the first and second flip is the same thing as getting a heads on both the first and second flip, which is straightforward to calculate.

Comment: Edited the question with another, well is kind of homework self-study.

Comment: The trick is to get the event A and B to mean something that you know how to calculate the probability for using the binomial distribution. For example, $p(2H|T1=H)$ can be written as $p(2H \mbox{ and } T1=H)/p(T1=H)$. Now the bottom one is easy to find, right? The top one, 2 heads and toss one is heads, can be thought of as the union of the event that toss one is heads, toss two is heads, and toss three is tails and the event that toss one is heads, toss two is tails, and toss three is heads. Computing these two probabilities is straightforward and adding them up gives you the numerator.

Comment: I don' get it, how? p(T1=H)=4/8 because we are fixing T1, isn't it? Then how do I get p(2H and T1). And how do i calculate p(T1=H) with the binomial is giving me 3/8, in matlab as binopdf(1,3,.5). :)

Comment: Think of P(T1=H) as the probability of getting 1 heads in 1 flip. What you're getting from matlab is the probability of 1 heads in 3 flips. See the difference?

Comment: Yes I see it now, that is 4/8 the denominator, and the numerator, how?